# A compressed trie dictionary built following the LZ78 algorithm is the same as a normal trie?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, compression

I'm implementing LZ78 as an exercise following the book Data Compression The Complete Reference(David Salomon et al.). In the book they suggest that a trie is an appropriate data structure for implementing a dictionary for LZ78.

As an example they show what the trie for "sir_sid_eastman_easily_teases_sea_sick_seals" would look like.

[LZ78 Dictionary Trie Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97YQK.png)

And the trie seems to be as compressed as can be. Is it always the case that a trie built following the LZ78 algorithm cannot be compressed?

Comment: What is a trie? Did you mean a tree?

Comment: A trie is a type of Tree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Can a trie normally be compacted? I thought the shape of a trie is completely determined by the input string

Comment: Yes it can, a "normal" tree has one character per node, and each terminal node have a unique value associated with it. A compacted trie however joins all nodes without values that only have one children, resulting in a trie that will possibly have an array of characters per node. I think that they might be called compressed tries however, when searching google I find it being called both compacted and compressed, but more frequently compressed.

Comment: Oh when I said normal tree I mean trie, my bad.